# std::equal not working when using vectors returned by a getter

Tags: c++, vector, stl

While learning about how `std::equal` works, I was writing some test code and ran into this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Foo {

public:
    std::vector<int> vec;

    Foo(std::vector<int> _vec) {
        vec = _vec;
    }

    std::vector<int> get() {
        return vec;
    }

};

int main() {
    
    std::vector<int> x{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> y{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    Foo a = Foo(x);
    Foo b = Foo(y);

    std::cout << std::equal(a.vec.begin(), a.vec.end(), b.vec.begin()) << "\n";
    // Outputs: 1

    std::cout << std::equal(a.get().begin(), a.get().end(), b.get().begin()) << "\n";
    // Outputs: 0 <-- why?

    std::cout << (a.get() == b.get());
    // Outputs: 1
}
```

When I compare two vectors that are returned by the getter function, they are not equal. Why is this?

I understand that if I return by reference in the method `std::vector<int>& get`, it'll print that the vectors are equal. However, I might need to use this getter method in a function that takes in a `const Foo&` argument. However, returning by reference isn't allowed in a const function (`std::vector<int>& get() const` is not allowed).

---

For my practical purpose, I will need to check that two vectors of doubles are equal by checking if each corresponding element's difference falls within a certain tolerance range. It looks something like this:

```
bool is_equal(double val1, double val2) {
    return abs(val1 - val2) < 0.0001;
}
```

Given 2 `Foo` objects `a` and `b`, I want to check if their vectors are equal (`vec` is private):

```
std::equal(a.get().begin(), a.get().end(), b.get().begin(), is_equal); // This won't work
```

For this reason I can't really use `a.get() == b.get()` (I would if I could) because rounding inaccuracies might give unwanted results.

Any insight on what's going on and what I can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, return by const reference

```
const std::vector<int>& get() const {
    return vec;
}
```

that solves the problem. An alternative would be to have two getters returning the begin and end iterator, instead of returning the vector itself.

Second, the reason for the problem is that your version of the getter **copies** the vector. so in

```
std::equal(a.get().begin(), a.get().end(), b.get().begin())
```

your iterators `a.get().begin()` and `a.get().end()` are pointing at two different vectors (both copies of the vector in the class).

Comment: To elaborate the reason: Passing begin/end iterators to different containers violates the preconditions of equal, and so the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: @eerorika Is that really the case? Aren't [overloads 1 and 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) here supposed to be called where `first1` and `first2` are iterators into different containers? Is it possible that the actual problem is that the temporary from `a.get()` has expired by the time `equal` is doing anything with `a.get().begin()`? ETA: Oh, I see what you're saying, the problem is that `a.get().begin()` is a beginning iterator to a different vector than `a.get().end()` is an ending iterator to.

Comment: @NathanPierson yep. And regarding `Is it possible that the actual problem is that the temporary from a.get() has expired`: No, the temporaries persist until the end of the full-expression, which is the function call.